# Multidimensional Javascript Array Syntax?

Tags: javascript, syntax, multidimensional-array

I cant seem to find a resource online for the syntax of multidimensional arrays, I was hoping someone here could identify the error, thanks.
I'm storing the array like this:

```
songs={{'title':'I Like It','artist':'Enrique Englesias','url':'audio/I Like It.mp3'},
{'title':'Driving Me Crazy','artist':'Sam Adams','url':'audio/driving me crazy.mp3'},
```

Then im calling them like this

```
document.write(songs[0]['artist']);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `{` where you mean `[`.

Try:

```
 songs=[{'title':'I Like It','artist':'Enrique Englesias','url':'audio/I Like It.mp3'},
        {'title':'Driving Me Crazy','artist':'Sam Adams','url':'audio/driving me crazy.mp3'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
songs = [{'title':'I Like It','artist':'Enrique Englesias','url':'audio/I Like It.mp3'},
  {'title':'Driving Me Crazy','artist':'Sam Adams','url':'audio/driving me crazy.mp3'}];
```

...but note this is an array of two objects, not a multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your songs array like so. This way you have an array of objects.

```
songs=[{'title':'I Like It','artist':'Enrique Englesias','url':'audio/I Like It.mp3'},
{'title':'Driving Me Crazy','artist':'Sam Adams','url':'audio/driving me crazy.mp3'}]
```

now you can do something like this

```
songs[0].title
```

Answer (score 0):

That isn't an array. It's an object hash. And a malformed one at that. You could access it as desired, but it needs to look like this:

```
songs=[{'title':'I Like It','artist':'Enrique Englesias','url':'audio/I Like It.mp3'},
    {'title':'Driving Me Crazy','artist':'Sam Adams','url':'audio/driving me crazy.mp3'}];
```